# How to take the max value for every element in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
    DNumber integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE Patient(
    PID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    P_DNumber integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Department (DNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Appointment(
    AppNumber integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AppDate date NOT NULL,
    App_DNumber integer  NOT NULL  REFERENCES Department (DNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Attend(
    A_PID integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Patient (PID),
    A_AppNumber integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Appointment(AppNumber)
);
```

HEllo, I have these tables and I want to find for each PID the last Date he attended an appointment. I tried with joins but nothing worked. I am using Postgres. Does anyone have an idea about it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try, joining through `Attend` and `Appointment`.

```
SELECT 
  Patient.PID,
  MAX(Appointment.AppDate) AS lastAttended
FROM 
  Patient 
  LEFT JOIN Attend ON Patient.PID = Attend.A_PID
  JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.AppNumber = Attend.A_AppNumber
GROUP BY Patient.PID
```

For patients attending 2+ appointments per month you need `COUNT()` inside a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT 
  Patient.PID,
  COUNT(Attend.A_AppNumber) AS numAppts
FROM 
  Patient 
  LEFT JOIN Attend ON Patient.PID = Attend.A_PID
GROUP BY Patient.PID
HAVING COUNT(Attend.A_AppNumber) >= 2
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfect with LEFT JOIN. Thank you very much.
If I can ask one more question, I want to find the PIDs that attend at least two appointments in a month.

Comment: @Cheryl see addition above, though technically by Stack Overflow regulations that should be asked as a separate question.  Welcome to SO, by the way.

Comment: @Cheryl If you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it. Welcome, once again, to SO.